# Cannot resolve ${url} in applicationcontext-ws.xml while running test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

An `url` is set with something like `http:xxx.com` in `..test/java/resources/application-local.properties` and `..main/java/resources/application-local.properties`

A file called `applicationcontext-ws.xml` used `${url}` :

```
<jaxws:client id="xxx"
              serviceClass="RemoteService"
              address="${url}">
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="headerInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```

When running test, I got an exception:

> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at
>   index 1: ${url}   at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063)  at
>   java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.setupURI(HTTPConduit.java:664)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:458)

However, when running it normally, i.e., not running test, this problem never occurs.

At first I suspect that it's because `..test/resources/application-local.properties` is not loaded. I annotate a field `url` with  `@Value(${url})` in my test class, and in debug mode I can see the field's value is exactly the url's content in `..test/resources/application-local.properties`, so that's not the cause.

Would you please offer some advice to help me figure out what's the cause and how to resove `url` while running test? Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more details about your test setup and the test itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe '${url}' itself is going as the url and '{' is being treated as an illegal character. Please debug and check what is the url that is being passed/created at runtime. I believe  ${url} is not getting replaced correctly at runtime.